# Prove that $\mathbb{P}(X > \lambda \mathbb{E}[X]) \geq (1-\lambda)^2\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]^2}{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{P}(X > \lambda \mathbb{E}[X]) \geq (1-\lambda)^2\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]^2}{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}$ for all non-negative random variables X with $0 \leq \lambda < 1$.

I have tried many different paths, however the most successful one so far involves the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, which states:
$$\mathbb{E}[X Y] \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Y^2]}$$
This implies:
$$\mathbb{E}[Y^2] \geq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X Y]^2}{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}$$
Now I think with a proper choice for Y I might be able to obtain the statement I am trying to prove. I tried for instance $Y=1-\lambda$ which I believe leads to:

$$(1-\lambda)^2 \geq (1-\lambda)^2\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]^2}{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}$$
This is the closest I got to the statement, however now I would have to prove that $\mathbb{P}(X > \lambda \mathbb{E}[X]) \geq (1-\lambda)^2$ at which I got stuck.

Am I trying the right things here or am I completely going down a dead path? If so, what could be a sensible choice for $Y$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not true. Let $X$ be non-degenerate and take $\lambda\to 1$ to have $RHS\to 0$ while $LHS$ is $\Theta(1)$.

Comment: Actually, it's exactly the other way round: $$\mathbb{P}(X> \lambda \mathbb{E}(X)) \color{red}{\geq} (1-\lambda)^2 \frac{\mathbb{E}(X)^2}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)},$$ this is known as Paley-Zygmund inequality.

Comment: Just noticed my typo as well, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cauchy Schwarz inequality is a good idea.

1. Show using the Cauchy Schwarz inequality that
   $$\mathbb{E}(X 1_{\{X \geq \lambda \mathbb{E}X\}}) \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} \sqrt{\mathbb{P}(X \geq \lambda \mathbb{E}X)}. \tag{1}$$
2. Show that $$\mathbb{E}(X 1_{\{X \geq \lambda \mathbb{E}X\}}) \geq (1-\lambda) \mathbb{E}(X). \tag{2}$$ (Hint: $1_{\{X \geq \lambda \mathbb{E}X\}}) = 1- 1_{\{X < \lambda \mathbb{E}X\}})$.)
3. Combine $(1)$ and $(2)$ to prove the claim.

**Remark:** This inequality is known as Paley-Zygmund inequality.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a little bit clearer proof of the [Paley–Zygmund inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality) on Wikipedia. The idea is the same, but it is a little bit clearer. The proof goes as follows.

First, 
$$
\operatorname{E}[Z] = \operatorname{E}[ Z \, \mathbf{1}_{\{ Z \le \theta \operatorname{E}[Z] \}}]  + \operatorname{E}[ Z \, \mathbf{1}_{\{ Z > \theta \operatorname{E}[Z] \}} ].
$$
The first addend is at most $\theta\operatorname{E}[Z]$, while the second is at most $\operatorname{E}[Z^2]^{1/2} \operatorname{P}( Z > \theta\operatorname{E}[Z])^{1/2}$ by the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality. The desired inequality then follows.

Comment: Actually this is exactly the same proof as in my answer...

Comment: @saz Yes, it is. But it is a little bit clearer when we begin by splitting the expected value into two parts. Probably, I could've written a comment instead of posting it as an answer.